# Python - does a variable inside the for loop get created only once or once per iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop

In the following for loop, how many times is `x` created (i.e. how many times is a new piece of memory allocated) - only once or once per iteration? I'm assuming it's the former, but I'd like to be sure.

```
for _ in range(10):
    x = 3
```

Comment: Semantically it gets freed and then recreated each time through the loop, but a good optimizer would notice this and refactor the bytecode. Are you asking about the principle or actual practice (and in the latter case then for which Python implementation(s) exactly)?

Comment: I'm asking about the actual practice. I didn't have a specific Python implementation in mind, but I guess cPython is what I'm interested in, as it's the most widely used one.

Comment: A good coder would recognize this and remove the not needed loop before the python optimizer would ever get a look at it. if something more is going on, the coder would pull the `x = 3` before the loop as it is not changing inside it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disassembling the generated byte code is instructive:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, May 18 2021, 11:47:11) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('''for _ in range(10):
...   x = 3''')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 18)
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (_)

  2          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (x)
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Perhaps notice that `LOAD_CONST` does not as such create a new memory allocation; but the `STORE_NAME` for `x` is indeed inside the loop.